# CentOs+SVN: Setup SVN for vhosts

Tags: apache, svn, tortoisesvn, centos

I have a Centos 6 server with multiple vhosts setup as shown below:

```
/var/www/vhosts/website1/httpdocs/
/var/www/vhosts/website2/httpdocs/
/var/www/vhosts/website3/httpdocs/
```

they can be accessed through

```
www.site1.com
www.site2.com
www.site3.com
```

I installed svn through yum install ..

I updated my subversion.conf according to the site I want to control. I wanted to control a folder called images inside httpdocs:

```
<Location /test>
  DAV svn
  SVNParentPath /var/www/vhosts/site1/httpdocs/
  AuthType Basic
  AuthName "Subversion Repositories"
  AuthUserFile /etc/svn-auth-users
  Require valid-user
</Location>
```

I created a password file named svn-auth-users

When I enter in svn tortoise the url: http://www.site1.com/test it gives me an error:
Could not open the requested svn filesystem.

For information I did not used the svnadmin create images. Since this images folder already exists and is not empty.

Any help will be appreciated since I am really stucked.

Update: I changed the owner of repository and parent folder to apache:apache.. still same error

Thank you.

Comment: Duplicate: [SVN could not open the requested svn filesystem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15859229/svn-could-not-open-the-requested-svn-filesystem), [Ubuntu SVN could not open the requested filesystem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12644827/ubuntu-svn-could-not-open-the-requested-svn-filesystem).

Comment: I followed the answers on the other questions.. I get an error message of redirect cycle...

Comment: I changed the subversion.conf... I Had again the filesystem error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said:

> "I did not used the svnadmin create images. Since this images folder
>   already exists and is not empty."

An existing non-empty directory cannot be just "reused" as a SVN repository. Instead, do something along these lines to create a new repository on your server from the content of an existing directory:

```
svnadmin create /var/www/vhosts/site1/httpdocs/images-repo/;
cd /var/www/vhosts/site1/httpdocs/images-repo/;
mkdir branches tags trunk;
cd trunk/;
cp -R /var/www/vhosts/site1/httpdocs/images/* .;
svn import -m "Initial import" http://www.site1.com/images-repo/;
```

(Note that it's not good practice to store your repository data inside the document root, security-wise.)